# I can't transfer my Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

After downloading the July 30th update, I noticed the ability to Transfer my Pokemon was gone.

[image: No Transfer button?]

Is this a bug or is everyone experiencing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They just cleaned up the UI a little. By tapping on the pop-up menu icon, you can choose to Favourite, or Transfer your pokemon

[image: Menu icon]

[image: Transfer/Favourite]

Comment: "Cleaned up the UI" aka increased the number of steps to do the exact same thing. Seriously annoying. Same with Journal, do you know how used to (literally everyone) was to quickly tapping your trainer then tapping Journal?

Comment: @Insane agreed! "cleaning up the UI" would mean adding possibility to transfer multiple pokes at once.

Comment: @Insane no, now you don't have to scroll down and deal with the map pop. Just tap, tap, done.

Comment: @hobbs I personally never had that issue..

Comment: The weird part is that now you can favorite your pokemon both with the Star AND the bottom right menu. I'm not sure that's "cleaner".

Comment: @Insane. The number of steps definitely decreased. It used to be scroll, scroll, tap. Now it's tap, tap. Yes, it was always 2 scrolls because the map popped after the first. Personally I find how it now is much better and faster. And even if you somehow could do it in one scroll then scroll tap and tap tap are the same number of steps

Comment: Personally think that if they're going with a menu system like that, then that menu should include "Power up" and "Evolve"... but then again it wouldn't be able to easily show costs. Now I remember why I hate UI design but have to do it for my own projects XD

Comment: @IvoBeckers I literally never had this issue lol